# set even to 0 and odd to 1

Tags: java, arrays

I'm playing around with double arrays and am trying to set all the even elements of an array to 0 and all of the odd elements of the array to 1. Everything looks okay to me, but when I run it I get a bunch of errors. Not sure what's wrong; I've been looking at it for a while with no luck. Any advice on how to fix the errors it gives would be great, thanks!

Code:

```
public class SetOf0and1 {

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {

        int [][] numbers1 = {{4,2,5}, {2,4,1}, {1,3}};

        System.out.println("Before setting elements between 0 and 1: ");
        displayArray(numbers1);

        setEvenRowsTo0OddRowsTo1 (numbers1);
        System.out.println("After setting the elements between 0 and 1");
        displayArray(numbers1);

    }

    public static void setEvenRowsTo0OddRowsTo1(int [][]array)
    {
    for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<array[i].length;j++)
        {
            if(i%2 == 0)
            array[i][j]=0;
            else
                array[i][j]=1;

    }
    }
}
    public static void displayArray(int [][]array)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            for( int j=0; j<array.length;j++)
            {
                System.out.println(array[i][j] + " " );
            }
            System.out.println();

    }

    }

}
```

Errors given:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at SetOf0and1.displayArray(SetOf0and1.java:38)
    at SetOf0and1.main(SetOf0and1.java:10)
```

Comment: Note:`if(i%2 == 0) array[i][j]=0; else array[i][j]=1;` can be written more simply: `array[i][j] = i % 2;`

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void displayArray(int [][]array)
{
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        for( int j=0; j<array.length;j++)
                             ^^^^^^^^^
        {
            System.out.println(array[i][j] + " " );
        }
        System.out.println();
}
```

Your inner loop should stop at array[i].length.

Answer (score 2):

In the method `displayArray`, the line:

```
for( int j=0; j<array.length;j++)
```

Should be:

```
for( int j=0; j<array[i].length;j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

`array.length` does not return the length you thing it does! You have a 2 dimentional array. So if we say you have `array[x][y]` then `array.length` will be `x` and `array[i].length` (for `0 <= i  < x`) will be `y`. This could be different depending on the `length` of the array on that index. (so the formula does not exactly apply like that)

Answer (score 0):

```
int [][] numbers1 = {{4,2,5}, {2,4,1}, {1,3}};
```

this statement initializes an array with three arrays of the legthes 3, 3 and 2!!!

(in the third block you have only two elements !!! - {1,3})

In your displayArray-method you use two times ...

```
array.length
```

... to distinct the size of the loop

that sets the number of loops to 3 ... But last block is only two elements long -> errror.

Use this instead for the second loop:

```
for( int j=0; j<array[i].length;j++)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check if a number is odd, you can do it this way:

```
int answer = thenumber % 2;
```

'thenumber' is the integer to check if it is even.
Then 'answer' would be 0 if the number was even.

And if you want to loop through the array and do it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers1.length(); i++)
{
if (numbers1[i] % 2 == 0) {
//EVEN
numbers1[i] = 0;
}
else if (numbers1[i] % 2 == 1) {
//ODD
numbers1[i] = 1;
}
}
```

And, even more compact:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers1.length(); i++)
{
numbers1[i] %= 2;
}
```

**Edit:** I forgot that it was an array you had! I was thinking about ArrayList! Fixed.